# UITableView editing - select cell without cell highlighting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have images in my tableView cells, so I have set the cell selectionStyle to None, in order to avoid the cells highlighting when they're selected.

I'm now trying to implement editing into the tableView, allowing users to select multiple cells, filling in the checkmark cirle on the left of the cells. However, this doesn't seem to work with a selectionStyle of None - the circle just remains unfilled.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't select the cells directly you can place a uibutton in the cell and recognize in which cell the button that was tapped was.To do that you can set the button tag to equal the indexPath.row inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

The code below prints the correct row number. Hope this helps.

```
  class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var onButton: UIButton!

    }

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {

        let buttonRow = sender.tag
        print(buttonRow)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.onButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.onButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }}
```